# Modern grammar theories for serial language learning

Tags: learning-methods, grammar

When learning multiple foreign languages, would it be worthwhile investing time into mastering modern grammar theories (generative grammars, construction grammars, etc.) or are those too theoretical for practical use?

I will be particularly interested in the study manuals for specific languages, explaining grammar in theoretical terms (as opposed to the conventional descriptive grammar approach).

**Example:**
Here is one such book that I found [*Foundations of French syntax* by Michael Allan Jones](https://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/semantics-and-pragmatics/foundations-french-syntax?format=PB) (Cambridge University Press, 1996). This seems to be a grammar aimed at advanced learners of French which in the same time may serve as an introduction to transformational generative grammars as applied to this language (rather than usual English).

Comment: Could you please reword your question to clarify what its focus is? Do you want to know (a) if learning grammar theory is helpful or (b) where you can find academic descriptions of grammar? These should be two separate questions. Moreover, the second question should cover one language only.

Comment: I have reformulated the question. Since it is about the methods of learning, I feel that it would be unwise to confine it to a specific language. However, you may want to move it to the linguistics forum.

Comment: Don't worry, I'd rather not migrate a question that is on topic here.